# Geometry vocabulary.

Tags: geometry, terminology

Does anyone know how i can describe the point "x" that's in the picture?

my best attempt so far is to say

*The point X is on the extended line segment of DE and lies outside $\triangle ABC$ and is on side AC*

Is saying "on side AC" too vague or even correct?

[image]

Comment: The reflection of E across AC?

Comment: It's not a reflection unfortunately

Comment: Can you just say x is an exterior point of triangle ABC that lies on the unique line determined by D and E?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would phrase it this way.

> The point $X$ is on the line through $DE$, such that the line through $AC$ separates  the interior of $\triangle ABC$ and $X$.

Comment: Do you needed to add "and X"?

Comment: @jak Yes. Otherwise $X$ could be on the wrong side. An alternative is " ....such that the line through AC separates $B$ and $X$."

Answer (score 1):

IMO saying 'X' lies on ED extended should make clear what you would like to convey.

Comment: But it could be on the side of AB.

Comment: Had it been that ways I would take care to mention DE extended instead.